# How to detect app visibility on Windows 10

Tags: winjs, windows-10-universal

Is there a way to see if your app is in the foreground or not in windows 10.  I'm trying to alert the user to event using toast but rather not have it popup when the app is already in view.  I'm using html/js.

Thanks

Comment: is there a way to know if the OS start menu is displaying also, since its covering the app, it would be nice to fire a toast there too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for this event:

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function ()
{
    var state = document.visibilityState; // 'hidden' or 'visible'
});
```

You can store the current state and decide whether to show your toast message based on that.

Update: changed msvisiblitychange to visibilitychange, if you are pre-Win10 you may still need the 'ms' prefix

Comment: as i found out its just 'visibilitychange'. the 'ms' part got axed in windows10

Comment: @Vinh If this answered your question, kindly mark as the accept answer please.  It's what makes the StackOverflow world go round :)